# What happens if I weak link all of the frameworks in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, weak-linking

What happens if I weak link all of the frameworks in my app? Can anything bad happen?

Comment: Yes, your app will be so brittle that dropping a device would crash it.

Comment: But in all seriousness, why would you want to weak-link everything?

Comment: @BoltClock I think this is an interesting question, academically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@timesking:

What is the need to do so?

I suppose app would try to run even if some of the required frameworks are not present in particular version of iOS and then would end up crashing.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good idea. While *technically* nothing bad will happen, weak linking allows you to write code that might crash. Weak linking tells the compiler that your program should keep running, even if parts of a library are unsupported. If you don't weak link, the presence of an unsupported method call or object will crash the app. If you do, The app will run until you try to access the bad symbol. So, not weak linking everything gives you the added benefit of not having to debug obscure cases.

Not weak linking is about what you don't lose, not what you gain - unless you need backward compatibility. Then the story changes.

Check out [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Moving Library to weak will help you to handle (older) devices where this library is not available, and then allow your application to start.

Then moving a library to weak is not sufficient cause you will for sure need to handle code that use this library carefully, as explained in [SDK documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html) otherwise your application will crash when the library would get used (if not supported).

Hope this helps.